# Can't Symbolicate Monotouch iOS App Crash Log

Tags: ios, crash, xamarin.ios, symbolicatecrash

I've searched and found a number of StackOverflow Q/A's regarding this topic, but I still cannot get my iOS MonoTouch App's crash logs to symbolicate.  Here's my environment info:

```
MonoDevelop 2.8.5  
Runtime:  
Mono 2.10.6 (tarball Fri Sep 16 00:13:06 EDT 2011)  
GTK 2.24.5  
GTK# (2.12.0.0)  
Apple Developer Tools:  
 Xcode 4.2 (828)  
 Build 4D199  
Monotouch: 5.0.4  
Operating System:  
Mac OS X 10.7.2  `
```

Of course when I build the app in Monodevelop, I have it set for the Debug|iPhone configuration which enables debugging and emits debug symbols.  I can verify that a dsym file is being generated also.

EDIT - One other piece of info that may be relevant.  Xcode Organizer tells me that it cannot find the software image that matches the version on my phone (5.0.1 - 9A405). [image: Organizer Screenshot]

When I plug my device in (iPhone 4S), the logs get imported, and the Organizer Window reports that it is symbolicating the logs.  However, I only end up with locations and offsets in the logs:

```
Application Specific Information:
IMDSSMobile_iOS[22522] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <SBProcessAssertion: 0x11c36880> identifier: Suspending process: IMDSSMobile_iOS[22522] permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner pid:15 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI 
)}

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.410 (user 2.410, system 0.000), 12% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.003, 0% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x339da0d8 0x339c9000 + 69848
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3655bc44 0x36559000 + 11332
2   IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x005b8f60 0x1000 + 5996384
3   IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x00544208 0x1000 + 5517832
4   IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x00545c24 0x1000 + 5524516
5   IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x005b31bc 0x1000 + 5972412
6   IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0054e248 0x1000 + 5558856
7   IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0054c178 0x1000 + 5550456
8   IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0054d4bc 0x1000 + 5555388
9   IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x00560620 0x1000 + 5633568
10  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0057a88c 0x1000 + 5740684
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x365b1532 0x36559000 + 361778
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3655bc44 0x36559000 + 11332
13  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0063d654 0x1000 + 6538836
14  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0063f224 0x1000 + 6545956
15  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x005c6b30 0x1000 + 6052656
16  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x002ef91c 0x1000 + 3074332
17  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x002eca04 0x1000 + 3062276
18  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x002e7780 0x1000 + 3041152
19  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x002e76e8 0x1000 + 3041000
20  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x002d7f24 0x1000 + 2977572
21  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x002d7cbc 0x1000 + 2976956
22  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0036c220 0x1000 + 3584544
23  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0036c104 0x1000 + 3584260
24  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0042dec4 0x1000 + 4378308
25  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0042d88c 0x1000 + 4376716
26  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x004305b8 0x1000 + 4388280
27  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0045af54 0x1000 + 4562772
28  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x006c0e54 0x1000 + 7077460
29  Foundation                      0x31fff2f2 0x31fd6000 + 168690
30  Foundation                      0x31ffee2c 0x31fd6000 + 167468
31  Foundation                      0x31fd8f12 0x31fd6000 + 12050
32  CoreFoundation                  0x3809f7fc 0x38087000 + 100348
33  CoreFoundation                  0x380a048a 0x38087000 + 103562
34  UIKit                           0x3576c4b8 0x354f5000 + 2585784
35  UIKit                           0x356dc9c4 0x354f5000 + 1997252
36  UIKit                           0x355bbe9a 0x354f5000 + 814746
37  UIKit                           0x35531784 0x354f5000 + 247684
38  UIKit                           0x355923b2 0x354f5000 + 644018
39  UIKit                           0x35592350 0x354f5000 + 643920
40  UIKit                           0x35591c8a 0x354f5000 + 642186
41  UIKit                           0x355919be 0x354f5000 + 641470
42  UIKit                           0x3558eb30 0x354f5000 + 629552
43  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x00456b38 0x1000 + 4545336
44  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0001927c 0x1000 + 98940
45  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x003856b8 0x1000 + 3688120
46  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x005361a4 0x1000 + 5460388
47  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0062e4b0 0x1000 + 6476976
48  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x006c19e0 0x1000 + 7080416
49  UIKit                           0x355ab55e 0x354f5000 + 746846
50  UIKit                           0x35623ce0 0x354f5000 + 1240288
51  Foundation                      0x3207193c 0x31fd6000 + 637244
52  CoreFoundation                  0x38114a5c 0x38087000 + 580188
53  CoreFoundation                  0x381146c2 0x38087000 + 579266
54  CoreFoundation                  0x38113298 0x38087000 + 574104
55  CoreFoundation                  0x380964d6 0x38087000 + 62678
56  CoreFoundation                  0x3809639e 0x38087000 + 62366
57  GraphicsServices                0x37c14fc6 0x37c11000 + 16326
58  UIKit                           0x3552673c 0x354f5000 + 202556
59  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0045aaa8 0x1000 + 4561576
60  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x00002d38 0x1000 + 7480
61  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x003856b8 0x1000 + 3688120
62  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x005361a4 0x1000 + 5460388
63  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0062e4b0 0x1000 + 6476976
64  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x006315d8 0x1000 + 6489560
65  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x006305d8 0x1000 + 6485464
66  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x0053d254 0x1000 + 5489236
67  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x005305c0 0x1000 + 5436864
68  IMDSSMobile_iOS                 0x00002bc0 0x1000 + 7104
```

Anyone have any other pointers?  I have a general idea of when the crash is happening, and I  realize that this error (assertions beyond a permitted time) usually involves doing blocking network IO on the main thread, but I'm not doing that and I can't tell what else might be going on.  It would probably be very helpful to see a valid stack trace from the log.

Comment: The app that crashed must be the last build in MonoDevelop (i.e. if you build & upload & run your app, it crashes, and then rebuild your project in MonoDevelop, the crash log won't be symbolicated)

Comment: Rolf - I do believe that is the case. I would build, upload, run & crash, then try to look at the report.

Comment: You should try to run "symbolicatecrash -v path/to/log.crash path/to/app.DSYM" and see if any errors are printed out (or put the verbose output here so other people can diagnose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

symbilication has nothing to do with MT or other technology used to generate native iOS app image.

System is trying to symbolicate the outbput, but this is done via loading data from dSYM file, you need to make sure you have the dSYM file in the same directory as the crash log, or do it manually with the explicit path to the dSYM.

Hope this helps.

-Pavel

Comment: I copied the crash log and the dsym file to a common directory, then imported the log into Organizer with good results.  Thanks Pavel.